# Convert simple SQL Query to WordPress query

Tags: custom-post-types, mysql, wpdb

I'm trying to 'batch' update the value in my post_parent fields in my wp_posts table. I can do it from within phpmyadmin using the following SQL Query:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_parent = '8' WHERE post_type = 'the_name_of_my_post-type_here';
```

but I can't get it to work from within wordpress.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are looking for is [`wp_update_post()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post).

You would want to have your posts which you want to update, then set up a loop to update each one individually.

```
// However you get your posts, ID's, etc.
$posts = get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'post' ) );

for ( $posts as $post ) {
    wp_update_post( array( 'ID' => $post->ID, 'post_parent' => 8 ) );
}
```

For a generic SQL call, look at the [`$wpdb`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) object, and it's [`prepare`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) and [`query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Running_General_Queries) functions:

```
global $wpdb;

$query = $wpdb->prepare( 'UPDATE wp_posts SET post_parent = %d WHERE post_type = %s', 8, 'my-post-type' );

$wpdb->query( $query );
```

You could also look into [`$wpdb->update`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows) - it may suit your needs better in the future.

Comment: I'll give that a go Eric. Thanks for the quick reply. Will let you know how I get on.

Comment: If you want to run that **exact** query from within WordPress, just use the global `$wpdb` object's `query' and 'prepare' functions. Adding example in answer.

Comment: I did not try the loop method so I cannot comment on it. For the $wpdb object, your code as written didn't cause any errors but not did it perform any changes to the post_parent fields. In the end I tried a very similar piece of code that worked for me `global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "UPDATE $wpdb->posts SET post_parent = %d WHERE post_type = %s",8, 'my-post-type' ) );` . So, what's the best way to accept answer here etc? ... I don't use stackexchange that much but want to ensure any future visitors are helped.

Comment: Yes, I guess I forgot to add `$wpdb->query( $query );` to the end of mine. :)